# JSON format for Google chart stacked column

Tags: javascript, php, json, charts

I have data like below:

```
           store 1   Store 2
store_id   walk-ins  walk-ins
morning      20        25
noon         35        40
night        50        55
```

There are 20 stores to chart stacking the values of each row.

Google Charts docs tells me the data array looks like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Stores', 'Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3', 'Store 4', ... ],
        ['morning', 10, 24, 20, 32, 18, 5, ...],
        ['noon', 16, 22, 23, 30, 16, 9, ...],
        ['night', 28, 19, 29, 30, 12, 13, ...],
      ]);
```

I am getting the data via MySQL script / server PHP script. What should the JSON look like? The `json_encode($data)`  from MySQL query returns as follows;

[{"store_name":"Store 1","Time":"Morning","count":"17"}, ...]

but the chart does not load and gives me a message "`Table has no columns`".

I load JSON as follows:

```
var url =  '/url/updatedata.php?var=querytype';
    jQuery.getJSON( url, function(Json) {

    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(Json);
....
```

What is the structure of the JSON for a stacked column chart?

Thanks!

Comment: You should map your json array to such data table yourself by using the `map` function like `Json.map(function(item) { return ['morning', 10, 16, 28]; })`

Comment: Also read documentation how the `google.visualization.DataTable` constructor should be used: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that mapping of your data happened to be a quite complex task.

For example, you have this json data:

```
var json = [
    {"store_name":"Store 1","Time":"Morning","count":"10"}, 
    {"store_name":"Store 1","Time":"Noon","count":"16"},  
    {"store_name":"Store 1","Time":"Night","count":"28"},    
    {"store_name":"Store 2","Time":"Morning","count":"24"}, 
    {"store_name":"Store 2","Time":"Noon","count":"22"},  
    {"store_name":"Store 2","Time":"Night","count":"19"}
];
```

I use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for the following code. It can be included like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Mapping code:

```
var header = _.chain(json).pluck("store_name").sort().uniq(true).value();
header.unshift("Stores");

var rows = _.chain(json)
.groupBy(function(item) { return item.Time; })
.map(function(group, key) { 
    var result = [key];
    _.each(group, function(item) { 
        result[_.indexOf(header, item.store_name)] = parseInt(item.count); 
    });
    return result; 
})
.value();

var jsonData = [header].concat(rows);

// draw chart
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

The final `jsonData` variable looks so:

```
[["Stores", "Store 1", "Store 2"], 
["Morning", 10, 24], 
["Noon", 16, 22], 
["Night", 28, 19]]
```

Here is a link to [jsFiddle with your chart](http://jsfiddle.net/Cg79c/).

Comment: Good, eventhough it have been better to format the JSON from PHP since OP query the db.

Comment: Hi vortex, you rock!! But I am looking for the data charted by store not by time. I will play with your fiddle to achieve this. MANY THANKS!

Comment: @TheRealPapa What you want to do is called `transpose of a matrix`, a simple algorithm. Or you can replace in my code all occurences of store_name by Time and accordingly Time by store_name.

Comment: Hi @vortex, I did already so THANK YOU! You really helped out (twice!). I have another q here if you want to make it a "hat trick" (Aussie thing!). I am now trying to get google.visualization.Table working! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168129/google-arraytodatatable-invalid-row-type-for-row-0. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post, but in case if any one needs it, here is the format for Jsondata for using google's stacked column from server code.

```
{
  "cols": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "title",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "A",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "role": "annotation",
      "p": {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "B",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "role": "annotation",
      "p": {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "C",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "role": "annotation",
      "p": {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "label": "D",
      "pattern": "",
      "type": "number"
    },
    {
      "type": "string",
      "role": "annotation",
      "p": {
        "role": "annotation"
      }
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "c": [
        {
          "v": "Categories",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "10",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "10",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "20",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "20",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "30",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "30",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "50",
          "f": null
        },
        {
          "v": "50",
          "f": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can i know the full form of "p","v","f"?