# Google arrayToDataTable - Invalid row type for row 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I am stuck (again!) and cannot seem to find an example for this. I have tried multiple variations of extracting and formatting the data to no avail.

I have the following data which comes in JSON format via server script:

```
[{ 
   "franchisee_name":"John Smith",
   "dish_menu":"Breakfast",
   "dish_title":"Bagels",
   "hq_price":"9.00",
   "store_price":"18.00",
   "valid_from_date":"2014-04-13",
   "valid_to_date":"9999-12-31"
 },
 {
   "franchisee_name":"Sam Jones",
   "dish_menu":"Breakfast",
   "dish_title":"Muesli",
   "hq_price":"8.00",
   "store_price":"13.00",
   "valid_from_date":"2014-04-13",
   "valid_to_date":"9999-12-31"
  },  ......
```

I want to place it into a Google Visualization table using

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

I understand the data needs to look like below:

```
['Franchisee', 'Menu Type','Dish', 'HQ Price', 'Store Price', 'Valid From', 'Valid To'], <-- header row         
['John Smith',  'Breakfast', 'Bagels', '9.00', '18.00', '2014-04-13', '9999-12-31'], <-- data row
....
```

My code for doing this is:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, function( data ) {

   var header = ['Franchisee', 'Menu Type','Dish', 'HQ Price', 'Store Price', 'Valid From', 'Valid To'];            
   var row = "";            
   var rows = new Array();

   jQuery.each( data, function( i, d ) {
    row = [ d.franchisee_name, d.dish_menu, d.dish_title, int(d.hq_price), int(d.store_price), d.valid_from_date.toString(), d.valid_to_date.toString() ];
    rows.append(row);
   });  

   var jsonData = [header].concat(rows);
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

   // Set chart options
   var options = {
    showRowNumber: 'false'
   };

   // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
   var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('hq_report_div'));
   chart.draw(data, options);   
});
```

But I get the error `Invalid row type for row 0` and have not found an example of how to tackle this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring `var data` in your callback function, you fall prey to the [hoisting mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) of javascript and its accompanying scopes subtleties<sup>1</sup>. Basically, your declaration goes to the top of the function and masks your named argument : `data` isn't equal to `[...]` but to `undefined`, see this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dVaC2/ to illustrate my point.

Rename your variable to `gdata` for example (and use `parseInt()` instead of `int`() and `[].push` instead of `[].append`) :

```
var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
// ...
chart.draw(gdata, options);
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/dVaC2/1/

---

<sup>1</sup> See http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html or [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506844/javascript-function-scoping-and-hoisting) for example